# PTIJ: What is "Meta" halakhah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've come across a [number](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568219016) of [references](http://www.leibowitz.co.il/leibarticles.asp?id=86) to a [concept](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=sHWeWWfHPPgC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=meta%20halakhah&source=bl&ots=JwXpZ4RBNQ&sig=ACfU3U2H9JdUVFXgFVUWkBaxU_6NugrlUg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIweLZqPjgAhUJqaQKHYcoDIc4FBDoATAGegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=meta%20halakhah&f=false) called "Meta-Halakhah".

I can only assume that it refers to the laws of using [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/), but I haven't been able to find many details.

So, what does the *halakhah* say about Meta?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a topic one should stay away from.

In the beg. of chapter 2 of Tractate Hagigah the sages warn of studying certain areas of Torah; areas commonly described as deep, abstract concepts (meta-Torah) which one should not engage in under normal circumstances. Such concepts are elusive and difficult to grasp and likely for a person to misunderstand/misinterpret. Basis can be found in the verse (Prov. 23:3):

> אַל־תִּ֭תְאָו לְמַטְעַמּוֹתָ֑יו וְ֝ה֗וּא לֶ֣חֶם כְּזָבִֽים

Loosely translated as: Do not crave for His *metas* (**מטע**עמותיו), for it is tricky bread.

Comment: Don’t forget that, among other catalysts, it’s because of Meta-tron that Acher went off the derech.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of important *halachot* to be aware of when it comes to Meta.

1. [Mishnah Yoma 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.6.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi):

> אֵין חַטַּאת צִבּוּר מֵתָה
>
> Meta is not the sin of the community.

If you see something egregious on Meta, don't cast aspersions on the entire community of Yodeyans (and certainly not on the Community user). Rather, simply downvote, comment or politely discuss your differences with the author of the post in Chat.

2. [Mishnah Sotah 9:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.9.15?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi)

> מֵתָה טָהֳרָה וּפְרִישׁוּת
>
> Meta is purity and ascetism.

Your motives must be pure to be a Meta contributor. Remember, there is no reputation to be won here.

3. [Bava Metzia 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.34a.10?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi):

> מתה מחמת מלאכה
>
> Meta is because of work.

Go on Meta when you're looking to procrastinate or distract yourself from the work you're meant to be doing.

4. Finally, when using Meta, it is important that we bear in mind the comment of [Tosefta Sotah 11:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sotah.11.4?vhe=Tosefta_Sota_-_Machon_Mamre&lang=bi):

> בזכות משה מתה
>
> We have Meta in the merit of [Isaac] Moses.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a mistake. Meta-Halacha isn't the laws about Mi Yodeya Meta, but rather halachos *from* Meta. The Meta site is where rules, contests, and other guidelines are made, so it's logical these would be called Meta-Halacha.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "yeshivish" form / transliteration of מיטה הלכה meaning "bedtime halacha". It's a yeshivish reference to the special behavior and halachot that apply in the yeshiva dorm bedroom.

For those unfamiliar, many dorm yeshivot have specific rules regarding what is allowed or not allowed in the dorms including proper behavior in one's room, the hallways, the restroom, showers, etc. While the term "meta" really means "bed", the yeshivish term is extended to the hallways and all other areas of the dorm, because yeshiva kids spend most of their time in the dorm for bedtime / sleeping purposes. Thus, the generic yeshivish term to these rules is called "meta halacha".

Even those fluent in yeshivish are not too familiar with this term if they have never been in a yeshiva dorm.

Answer (score 0):

I know of some Meta Halacha from Moses, at Sinai. For example in Masechet Sofrim 2:11, there is a Meta Halacha concerting torn scrolls.

> למטה הלכה למשה מסיני ספר תורה שנקרע מטלה עליו מטלית מבחוץ
>
> It is a Meta Halacha from Moses at Sinai, that if a Torah scroll is torn we place upon it a patch from the outside [and that is a valid method of repair].

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you misread the source. It's not "Meta" halacha, but "Metal halacha". It's much more loud and epic than normal halacha, but is otherwise similar.

For instance, normal halacha would be something like:

"Rabbi Eliezer said it's forbidden but Rabbi Akiva said it's permitted, and the halacha is according to Rabbi Akiva"

Metal halacha is like:

"Rabbi Eliezer busted out his Fender and darshened a rad kal vachomer about how totally Asur that was. Then Rabbi Akiva took out his Gibson and played  a wicked klal u'prat about how it was excellently Mutar. Then the Sanhedrin came in with their own gzeirot shavot which were totally more in harmony with Rabbi Akiva's svara. So when we jam on that theme, we now jam according to Rabbi Akiva."